# Power Law Fit of cut-off distribution with the poweRlaw package

Tags: r, graph, data-fitting, mle, power-law

I am currently trying to find a way to calculate a power-law fit for a cut-off distribution with MLE. The distribution looks as follows:

[image: Image1]

As you can see, I was able to fit the whole distribution (Power-law fit) and also the lower bound (exp-fit) separately. What I am failing to figure out, is how to fit the upper bound of the distribution (f.e. 8 < x < 100).

Is there any way to do this with the **poweRlaw** package or any other R package? What I am hoping for is something looking like this (note: it is just a random distribution):

[image: Image2]

Code (if necessary):

```
#Power-Law
library("poweRlaw")
xmin1 <- 8
xmin2 <- 100
plf0 <- displ$new(deg)
plf0$setXmin(xmin1)
plf0_pars <- estimate_pars(plf0)
plf0$setPars(plf0_pars)

#Exponential
exp1 <- disexp$new(deg)
exp1$setXmin(xmin2)
exp1_pars <- estimate_pars(exp1)
exp1$setPars(exp1_pars)
plot(plf0)
lines(plf0, col="green")
lines(exp1, col="red")
```

Comment: Is there a way to grab the parameters of the power-law fit equation?

Answer (score 0):

You can't fit this type of model with the `poweRlaw` package (I'm the package author).

It's unlikely to be added to the package in the near package.

Comment: Thank your for the quick answer. Do you have any other ways in mind how to address this topic?

Comment: Sorry, no (not that helpful I know)

Answer (score 0):

Following solution provides R code that can be run with Python using [rpy2](https://rpy2.bitbucket.io/).

It provides instructions based in the source code by [powerlaw](https://github.com/jeffalstott/powerlaw/) library, as suggested by the [answer by Kelvin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44747236/4928558), mainly from: https://github.com/jeffalstott/powerlaw/blob/master/testing/pli-R-v0.0.3-2007-07-25/powerexp.R file.

1. Install  [Gnu Scientific Library (GSL)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/)

   In Debian: `apt-get install libgl2`
2. Download [powerlaw](https://github.com/jeffalstott/powerlaw/) python library code from github.
3. unpack and build `exponential-integral.tgz` file located at `testing/pli-R-v0.0.3-2007-07-25/` folder of the previously downloaded library.

   ```
   tar xzf exponential-integral.tgz
   cd exponential-integral
   make
   ```
4. Move `exp_int` file to an executable path, named `yourexecutablepath` from here on.

   `mv exp_int yourexecutablepath`
5. Modify `exp_int_function_filename` variable from powerexp.R file with the full path to exp_int executable, i.e. `yourexecutablepath/exp_int`.
6. eval `exp.R`, `pareto.R` and `powerexp.R` R source code to include all the needed functions.
7. Fit your data to a powerlaw with exponential cut-off evaluating the following R call:

   ```
   data <- list(5, 3, ...)
   powerexp.fit(unlist(data))
   ```

The output of the last command provides several output values, among them `exponent` which gives the power law *alpha* value and `rate` which gives the exponential cut-off parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the R source code on [Aaron Clauset's page](https://aaronclauset.github.io/powerlaws/)? I mean the one by Cosma Shalizi, in section *Calculating likelihood-ratio test results*. It handles power laws with exponential cutoffs, according to the [documentation](https://aaronclauset.github.io/powerlaws/Rcode_README.txt).